# youtube mix two iframe livestream and playlist

Tags: live-streaming, playlist, youtube-iframe-api

i have two iframes

**iframe no.1 is livestream**

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="0" frameborder="0" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCSrZ3UV4jOidv8ppoVuvW9Q&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=1&amp;loop=1&amp;mute=01&amp;width=640&amp;height=500" width="100%"></iframe>
```

**iframe no.2  is playlist**

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="0" frameborder="0" weight=100% height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL9tY0BWXOZFsN7SmajqI2TZ0WWzJYQVsI&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=1&amp;loop=1&amp;mute=0" width="100%"></iframe>enter code here
```

i want mix these  two iframes  in fact when  youtube livestream activate
only show livestream at iframe 
and when livestream finished  iframe no2  start play automatically at  the same iframe

how set condition between them